# where can I find tcadsdll.dll?

Tags: twincat

I am running an example application using TwinCAT ADS communication system, got from a colleague.
When I give the command to connect to ADS, error ' fail to load tcadsdll.dll file ' appears; I have looked for it on the web but din't find

Answer (score 2):

I you have TwinCat 3.1 installed you find the dll in the following folder:

```
C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is the FTP page](ftp://ftp.beckhoff.com/software/TwinCAT/TwinCAT2/Supplement/TwinCAT_ADS_ServerFramework/) where you can download the packages for ADS development from beckhoff.

Just downlaod the [**CS_AdsServer.zip**](ftp://ftp.beckhoff.com/software/TwinCAT/TwinCAT2/Supplement/TwinCAT_ADS_ServerFramework/CS_AdsServer.zip) file and extract. You will find everything you need included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install TwinCAT to get the tcadsdll.dll file. You can request a download file on Beckhoff's website for free.

Comment: I download TwinCat and Add Reference but   I get this error 
    "TwinCAT.Ads.AdsInitializeException: 'ADS could not be initialized because the 'TcAdsDllCe.dll' is not found! Please check DLL search paths!"